# How to access date in next .then() - fetch api

Tags: javascript, function, promise, fetch

I wonder if there is a way to access data from then on the next one? Code looks like this:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${userObject.id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(user => {
          ...
        })
        .then(???)
```

and in second then I have all the needed info about the user. When I put everything in second then it works, but code is very messy and repetitive and I would like to put some things into function. Unfortunately, in that case, I don't have access to some data...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: why not return the data in the second `.then`?

Comment: `user => { /* ... */ return ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an argument to the next promise by returning it from the previous one.

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${userObject.id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(user => {
          return user.id;
        })
        .then(userId => {
          console.log('user id is:', userId);
        });
```

Also, you can accomplish same result by using async programming like bellow:

```js
async function fetchSomeData() {
  var res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${userObject.id}`);
  var user = await res.json();

  return user;
}

fetchSomeData().then(user => {
  console.log('user id is:', user.id)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> but code is very messy and repetitive and I would like to put some
>   things into function

Just use [async/await syntax](https://javascript.info/async-await), it's much more understandable.

```
(async() => {
    const request = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${userObject.id}`);
    const result = await request.json();

    // proceed to do whatever you want with the object....
})();
```

This is a self-executing function, but you can also declare this in the following way:

```
const myFunc = async() => {
    const request = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${userObject.id}`);
    const result = await request.json();

    // your logic here or you can return the result object instead;
};
```

or even without arrow functions:

```
const myFunc = async function() {
    const request = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${userObject.id}`);
    const result = await request.json();
    console.log(result.id);
};
```